# Disable USB charging

Tags: android, usb, android-source

For some reasons not related to the battery life, I need to disable the battery charging when a USB host is connected to my phone (a rooted Nexus 4).
Taking a look around on the internet ([link1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=787641&page=2), [link2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15001/how-can-i-avoid-the-battery-charging-when-connected-via-usb)), it looks like I should modify a system file. 
I have found a series of interesting files located in `/sys/class/power_supply/battery` and `/sys/class/power_supply/usb`, that could be the right ones to be modified in order to achieve the usb charging disabling (e.g. `/sys/class/power_supply/usb/present 0/1`). 
Has anyone tried something like that?
Which is the best way to modify those system files? Should I use the adb shell or another tool?

I tried the "root explore" app in order to modify those files, however when I modified a file (after changing its permissions), it was automatically kept back to its original value.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to a programming problem. The question would be better asked on http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I'll post my question there as well. Anyway, if someone has an idea please share.

Comment: Although file-like, those are not actual files, but sysfs nodes used for communicating with the kernel.  Their behavior really depends on the kernel modules which implement them.

Comment: This means they are not editable in "standard ways" then?