# Disable Android USB Charging

Tags: android, usb, nexus-7

I need to know a way, if possible, to disable USB battery charging while my Nexus 7 is plugged to my pc. I'm doing some tests on my devices and for better result I need the device plugged but not in charging. I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19316355/5743290) before, but the suggested path doesn't exit on my device. Has someone had my same problem before?

Comment: Check this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.guille.stopcharge maybe it will work for you

Comment: This app doesn't work on my Nexus 7. I've just tried it.

Comment: I need to do exactly this to stop my phone draining battery on my drones controller which plugs in to the phone

Answer (score 1):

No, there is an IC chip in mobile that monitors the various conditions like (phone/battery temperature, battery level etc..) and decides whether to charge it or not when charger is connected. This task is somehow H/w oriented operation. You cannot change the battery charging task.

However you can do one thing that will appear to user that battery is not charging. You can make the **battery charging icon** (in status bar) to **battery mode icon.** This can be achieved using Android `Broadcast`. You create the broadcast with intent `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` that will broadcast just after 1 sec of the default `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` intent broadcast and passes the relevant data with Bundle.

*Still Can you describe why you need to stop the battery charging.????*

Comment: I need to work with Batterystats (http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/batterystats-battery-historian/index.html) and Systrace (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html) at the same time, but the first needs to work unplugged unlike the second.

Comment: My answer would be that I'm continually USB debugging, and continuous charging (even at 100%) is very-very bad for the battery capacity

Answer (score 1):

I came here 6 years late but this works:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
```

or

```
adb shell dumpsys battery set usb 0
```

Comment: And to properly reset the phone settings after doing some test, use the following command : 
`adb shell dumpsys battery reset`

Comment: where to write this command

Comment: @blueberry `Terminal` on a mac, assuming you have `adb`

Answer (score -1):

The outer pins of a standard USB connector are used for power. You could try removing them from your cable, leaving only the inner data pins.

For more info on the pins, see http://pinouts.ru/Slots/USB_pinout.shtml

Comment: I've isolated the outer pins with non-conducting tape but when I plug the device it's not seen by ubuntu. Maybe because power is needed to link the device to the pc?

Comment: Won't work. USB uses the power lines to detect the connection, the data lines will not work without the power lines being connected. So if you need need USB connected the only way is to find a way to disable changing on the phone side.